# Which version of Ubuntu on Celeron with 1GB RAM is suitable?

Tags: nvidia

My computer has the configuration as follows:

- Intel Celeron processor
- 1GB RAM
- NVIDIA graphics support.

which version of Ubuntu will be suitable to develop drivers, kernel modules related works on my system?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend lubuntu 32 bit because it will be the lightest on resources.
[lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Download the 32 bit. It limits the usage of RAM and is compatible with ram amounts under 2gb